# How to change the color saturation of a contact sheet in Python?

Tags: python, image, rgb, pixel

I am not trying to get anyone to do my homework, I am just really struggling on a particular problem, and I haven't found any info so far online. So the goal of this problem is to create a contact sheet of 9 images where the intensity of the pixels in each image is varied. To explain further, the first row of three images is the red color channel, where the intensity of the red pixels is multiplied by a factor of 0.1, 0.5, or 0.9, so that the bluest images are on the far left (or where the intensity of the red channel is the lowest). The next two rows are the green and blue channels, where the intensities are varied across the row as above. I have the contact sheet with the 9 images already set up, I am just having difficulty varying the color intensity across the images.

I am using the PIL library, and it seems like the Image.getpixel(), Image.putpixel(), Image.split(), or Image.point() methods could be helpful, but I am just not understanding how to use them, or where to begin.

I have defined a function for the intensity of the image, now I am just having trouble changing the colors as needed. Any help would be appreciated. I am just beginning to learn how to code in python, and would love to continue to learn and improve my skills.

UPDATE: I have made some progress, but all of my images are cyan, even though I am looping over the different colors. The code runs fine, so it is a syntax error, but I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong.

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from PIL import ImageEnhance

# read image and convert to RGB
image=Image.open("readonly/msi_recruitment.gif")
image=image.convert('RGB')
images=[]
imglst = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

def intensity(intn):
    if intn==1:
        return .1
    elif intn==2:
        return .5
    elif intn==3:
        return .9

pixels=image.load()

for channel in imglst:
    for intn in channel:
        for x in range(image.width):
            for y in range(image.height):
                current_color = image.getpixel((x,y))
                r, g, b = current_color
                if imglst.index(channel) == 0:
                    r = r * intensity(intn)
                    new_color = (int(r), g, b)
                elif imglst.index(channel) == 1:
                    g = g * intensity(intn)
                    new_color = (r, int(g), b)
                elif imglst.index(channel) == 2:
                    b = b * intensity(intn)
                    new_color = (r, g, int(b))
                image.putpixel((x,y), new_color)
                images.append(image)
```

Comment: read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I thought I followed all of that...I don't know what doesn't follow those guidelines. But thank you for pointing me to that page.

Comment: I'm willing to fix anything that doesn't make sense or doesn't follow the guidelines of a good question, I just don't know what that is. If anyone points out problems that need to be fixed, I will gladly fix them.